# Finder: show specific EXIF data for RAW photos

Tags: finder, metadata, exif

I want to see the `focus distance` [exif](/questions/tagged/exif) data in the [finder](/questions/tagged/finder). This data is available for all the photos taken by the camera but the `Preview Options - Image` pane doesn't provide it. Consequently [finder](/questions/tagged/finder) cannot show it. It would be great if someone can suggest a way to do this?

[image]

Note, the 'exiftool' command line utility can show it (albeit, in cli) and Adobe Lightroom (albeit, not in finder).

Comment: Unfortunately, camera companies are not consistent when it comes to their RAW files.  They will often make changes to the format from camera to camera. Rendering the image requires exact details of the camera that produced it. Now, all of this shouldn't affect reading the EXIF data of a RAW file. But it would require the OS devs to deal with the oddities of each of the dozen or so different RAW file types. And I would guess that Apple/MS wouldn't feel it necessary to take the time to focus on what would only be  used by a smaller group of users

Comment: Also, just noticed that you are looking at a CR3 file.  CR3s are a completely different type of file from all other RAW file types.  Most RAW formats are based upon the TIFF file format.  CR3 are based upon the MP4 format. This is why if you include exiftool's [`-G` (`-groupNames`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#G-NUM-:NUM...--groupNames) in a command, you will see Quicktime video tags in the file.

Comment: Finally, an exiftool tip.  You can use asterisk wildcards when listing tags.  This is a better option than using grep because it will not suppress any warning/error/other messages that exiftool might print.  In this case, you could use this command: `exiftool '-*distance*' file.cr3` to list any tag that includes "distance" in the name.  On a Mac, I believe quotes are needed around arguments with asterisks to prevent file globbing.

Comment: Hmm, that's a bummer! But thanks for those infos! Have a question, if you know about it - why are there two focal distances (upper & lower), in stead of what Adobe LR shows? I did a mean: `(upper+lower)/ 2`, it shows similar value to it (not exact).

Comment: If you run the command in [Exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3), I suspect that you'll find these are part of the Canon MakerNotes. MakerNotes specs are rarely revealed by camera companies and only discovered through testing. Searching through the [Exiftool Forums](https://exiftool.org/forum) for these tags seems to indicate that these are basically what they say.  The upper and lower distances (probably in meters) of the focus.  Exiftool uses these in calculating its `Composite:DOF` tag.  For the most part, you can ignore MakerNote tags as very few programs acutally read them.

Comment: Thanks again. Seems like it's not something very 'standard'. My resort remains **exiftool** for the time being then... attaching for my reference: [DOF calculation with Canon?](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=6421.msg31935#msg31935)